# How to "ping" a domain name?

Tags: c#, dns, ping

In Code i want to validate a domain name.

For example : " DomainName.com".

How can i do that in C#.

I worked on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) Solution. (Second Solution).

But **"PingCompletedCallback" is not getting executed.**

Thanx

Comment: That won't validate the domain name - you'd be better off doing a DNS query instead

Comment: @Rowland yup, pinging a domain to validate it is totally useless.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do exactly.  Are you wanting to do a name lookup to check whether a domain name has been registered or are you wanting to test whether a particular host is up and responsive? Your tags seem to conflict with what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a class for that;

[MSDN Article on System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx)

[GeekPedia article on asynchronous ping](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial234_Asynchronous-Ping-using-Csharp.html)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think pinging a domain name will tell you anything relevant in a reliable way.

- A domain name can be registered but not connected to a server. Ping requests will fail even though the domain is registered.
- A server can be fully operational but be configured not to respond to ping requests. Ping requests will fail even if the domain is registered and running on a server.

What do you want to do - find out whether a domain is registered, whether it's a valid domain name, or whether it's a working website / mail server ...?

For the first two, I would recommend using a `whois` service. 
See for example these C# related questions:

- [How to get whois information of a domain name in my program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53623/how-to-get-whois-information-of-a-domain-name-in-my-program)
- [Parse whois answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413431/parse-whois-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Using the System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping class,

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

Ping sender = new Ping();
PingReply reply = sender.Send ("www.example.com");

if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Ping successful.");
}
```

It's untested, but that's the general idea.

Comment: I am getting :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: An exception occurred during a Ping request.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Ping class - here's all the info you need on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx)

Comment: I tried it But "PingCompletedCallback" is not getting executed.